# cocos2d-x label text char spacing

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use `cocos2d:::Label` and I need to control the spacing of adjustment characters in the text. I use cocos2d-x 3.0 and the font of the label is TTF. Is it possible to achieve, or I should use another thing instead of `cocos2d:::Label`?

Comment: +1 Good luck with this question! (tnat's just a friendly experiment of mine)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `(tnat's just a friendly experiment of mine)`? What you mean? :) Is it impossible?

Comment: I'm just trying out what dynamics are applied upvoting

Comment: afaik character spacing is an inherent attribute of the font (you'll find many fonts featuring "condensed" or "narrow" variants) - create your own ttf and you have full control over character spacing

Comment: I agree with @LearnCocos2D I think you need to subclass to have this control

Comment: What tool I can use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that bitmap fonts can be created with appropriate inter-character spacing. There is a [good online tool](http://kvazars.com/littera/) for that. And it can customize even more settings, and it is very handy.